# Difference between RxJS and IxJS?

Tags: rxjs, ixjs

*What's the difference between RxJS and IxJS, and when would I want to use one over the other?*

From the IxJS docs:

> RxJS is great for event-based workflows where the data can be pushed at the rate of the producer, however, IxJS is great at I/O operations where you as the consumer can pull the data when you are ready.

After going through the docs, the only major difference seems to be the concept of **Iterables in IxJS** and **Observables in RxJS**.

Both Iterables and Observables execute either synchronously or asynchronously, and the `.forEach` from IxJS is essentially the same as RxJS's `.subscribe` method when paired with the almost-identical `from` creator function. The only other difference is IxJS's `.forEach` method is optional because you could  use the imperative `for-of` instead.

It seems like there are two libraries for no reason because RxJS's `from` creator function can convert Iterables to Observables.

From my perspective, it's not really IxJS and RxJS, it's Iterables and Observables. How are they different and when would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## tl;dr

RxJS processes values as soon as they arrive. It's a **push** system.

IxJS specifies when to pass in the next value. It's a **pull** system.

## Explanation

`IxJS` may be helpful if want to have pull-based model, for example, when dealing with backpressure.

As you can see in the documentation:

> IxJS unifies both synchronous and asynchronous pull-based collections, just as RxJS unified the world of push-based collections. RxJS is great for event-based workflows where the data can be pushed at the rate of the producer, however, IxJS is great at I/O operations where you as the consumer can pull the data when you are ready.

In other words:

- Use `RxJS` if your producer (usually User) is slower that processing of data (this is common for frontend).
- Use `IxJS` if your producer (usually System) is much faster than you can process data (more common for the backend).

To understand what this means, consider the following example:

> You need to build ETL pipeline and process a large file (about 1TB).

If you write it with RxJS, something like:

```
readFileByLineObservable('path/to/file')
.pipe(
  doSomeHeavyTransformation(),
)
.subscribe()
```

Then `readFileByLineObservable` will try to "push" the entire file of 1TB into RAM as soon as possible. Only after this occurs, you will start to do `doSomeHeavyTransformation`. This problem is called [backpressure](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html).

In contrast, `IxJS` will try to "pull" each newline only after previous line was processed. That's the optimal processing method in this case.

The difference is how RxJS's `.subscribe` sets up a listener whereas IxJS's `.forEach` tells its iterator when to give the next value (only after its done processing the first one. It's similar to, but not the same as, RxJS's `concatMap` and `concatAll` operators.

Comment: Could you show the example of how IxJS does it differently for the file read? It seems like IxJS is more similar to Node.js streams.

Comment: Here is file reading example - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#async-generator-functions. Which can be converted using  `Ix.AsyncIterable.from` , then add some transformation operator - and this is it

Comment: @Oles Savluk In an RxJS implementation, it is likely that `doSomeHeavyTransformation` ends up in using `mergeMap` (a.k.a. `flatMap`). `mergeMap` has a parameter `concurrent` which you can use to limit the concurrency of processing. This is way to manage backpressure. If you want to process one line at a time, you just set `concurrent` to 1 or use `concatMap` which is exactly the same.

Comment: @Oles Savluk probably it depends on how you read the file. If you use node `readline` function you may end up with an Observable which does not need to read the entire file.

Comment: @Oles Savluk you may look at this example https://gist.github.com/EnricoPicci/2ca0c40c649cbb08f2dfcf43e96ad085 - I am not sure it answer your question, but this is the way I limit concurrency while reading files.

Comment: I think I get it. You're saying RxJS pushes data down the pipeline irregardless of how it's being processed, but IxJS waits for each value to completely pass through the stream before presenting the next, right? Or is that only the difference between sync and async on either library?

Comment: Yes, you got it right, **RxJS pushes** data, while **IxJS pulls** for data.

Comment: I wrote up an article on how to do IxJS-like functionality in RxJS: https://itnext.io/lossless-backpressure-in-rxjs-b6de30a1b6d4. Because `push` is lower-level than `pull`, you can use two pushes to simulate a pull with a lot more control than IxJS.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to [Oles Savluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3772379/oles-savluk) answer, I found Matt Podwysocki's explanation particularly useful (https://gist.github.com/mattpodwysocki/1d0fe43961c6222571386568b8a5ef23):

> we have four types of collections, each with their own purpose. Each
> has its own place, and there's no one solution that rules them all.
>
> ```
> Pull: Iterable - purely synchronous data, either finite or infinite
> Push: Observable / Subject/Observer - eventual data such as DOM events, collections over time
> Pull/Push: AsyncIterable - I/O or other asynchronous data where the consumer needs to be in control
> Push/Pull: AsyncObservable - Network calls where creation/teardown may be asynchronous as well as projections may be asynchronous too.
> ```

Matt is a contributor to both RxJS and IxJS.
Iterable and AsyncIterable come from IxJS, Observable and AsyncObservable are developed in RxJS

---